# GET request from Pokemon API in Python with Flask Framework

Tags: python, json, api, flask

I'm building an API that takes Name and Description info from https://pokeapi.co/ and translates the description with this https://funtranslations.com/api/shakespeare.

Current intention: I'm just trying to get the original 151 pokemon to appear as JSON on my server when I ask for http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/pokemon

Problem: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests, jsonify, json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Pokemon(Resource):
    def get(self, name, description):
        return info[name, description]

@app.route('/v1/pokemon/')
def orig_names():
  r = requests.get(
      'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151%27')
  return jsonify(r)
```

Comment: Which thing are you being told is a module object and therefore not callable, i.e. which line is the traceback indicating?

Comment: Can you provide the whole traceback?

Comment: Sure - Is there a way to print my traceback so I can make more it readable for you here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short

You are using the module jsonify and are calling it directly (which does not work, as the error says: a module is not callable).

Use the `jsonify` function from the `flask` module

```
from flask import jsonify
```

## Long

A module is a fancy name for a Python file with code (classes, functions, etc). The import statement allows you to import a module (i.e. including the code from the module inside your runtime). Importing the module, means you can execute functions and use classes from inside the module. It does not mean you can call the module itself.

The jsonify module is completely distinct (and different) from the jsonify function you intend to use: https://pypi.org/project/jsonify/

The jsonify function you want to use, is part of the Flask module (`from flask import jsonify`).
See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify

The function returns a Flask response object, up to you what data from the Pokemon api you want to encapsulate in the response!

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Pokemon(Resource):
    def get(self, name, description):
        return info[name, description]

@app.route('/v1/pokemon/')
def orig_names():
  r = requests.get(
      'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151%27')
  response_data = {} # up to you
  return jsonify(**response_data)
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeroen. When you say I can put whatever response in response_data..... Would I just call with name='name' inside the dictionary then?

Comment: With your API call you fetch the first 151 Pokemon. The `results` key of the response contains a list of Pokemon. If you want to return this list as a response, you can just use `jsonify(pokemon=r.get('results', []))`. This will return a JSON response with key `pokemon` and value a list of Pokemon (name + url). It allows you to show the Pokemon name on your webpage, and fetch additional info through the url.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers and responses. My desired result is to fetch all the names and description. Unfortunately I'm getting a: 
`AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'`  error 
when I try to implement this `jsonfiy ` function.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the Response object has no get() function. When you get the response object back from the `requests.get()` call, you can fetch the payload by using `response_json = r.json()`. This is a dictionary with the returned data, wich allows you to get the results (`pokemon_list = response_json.get('results')`)
I suggest you play around a bit with iPython to see what data is returned and how to manipulate it.

Comment: Amazing, will do. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you import the `jsonify` module and call it directly

```
jsonify(r)
```